# concatenate a variable in a string in inner join condition statements

Tags: mysql

I want to search a variable in a string in database in inner join condition statements. I want to raplace `wp_idpl_orders.product_id` with `%` in `ign_product_level_%_price` in the below query. How can I do this?

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_idpl_orders` INNER JOIN wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key like "ign_product_level_%_price" and wp_postmeta.meta_key like wp_idpl_orders.product_id and wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_idpl_orders.post_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL `CONCAT()` function is used to add two or more strings.

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_idpl_orders` INNER JOIN wp_postmeta WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key like concat("ign_product_level_",wp_idpl_orders.product_id,"_price") and wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_idpl_orders.post_id
```